# How to read specific line and specific position?

Tags: file, bash, shell, unix, solaris

I have a problem reading a string in specific line and specific position. I have an input file that has a fixed position and fixed length for each value in every row. This is an example of my input file:

```
sltele     Hoodie   24051988 d12Hdq
sltele     Hoodie   07051987 d30Hdq
sltele     Hoodie   07082011 d08Hdq
sltele     Hoodie   09081961 d04Hdq
sltele     Hoodie   20041962 d14Hdq
sltele     Hoodie   20032000 d01Hdq
sltele     Hoodie   13062002 d05Hdq
```

I need to read a string in 3rd column in first line. So, I used this

```
awk 'NR==1 {print $2, $3}' inputfile.inp
```

How can I get an exact result with character position as parameter? (12nd-18th and 21st-28th)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use `cut -c`

Check the man page for more details.

also you can use the below:

```
echo "abcdefghij" | awk '{print substr($0,2,2),substr($0,6,2)}'
bc fg
```

above is 2 characters from second position and 2 chars from 6th position.

your solution will be :

```
awk 'NR==1 {print substr($0,12,6),substr($0,21,7)}' inputfile.inp
```

the above command will get the 6 chars from 12th position and 7 chars from 21st position in line number 1.

Comment: Thank you peter :) That's the solution I want. thank you again :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use *sed* too:

```
sed -rn "1 s@.{11}(.{7}).{2}(.{8})@\1\2@p" filename
```

Explanation:

- **-n** don't print the lines
- **s** replace
- **1** only the first line
- **.{11}** omit 11 characters
- **(.{7})** save 7 characters (char 12-18)
- **.{2}** omit 2 chars (19-20)
- **(.{8})** save 8 chars (21-28)
- **\1\2** replace the string with the first and second saves
- **p** print the line specified line